# Sensor change doesn't trigger onSensorChanged

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I just started out on android and java yesterday, and i'm having a problem. I'm trying to output a sensor's values to some TextViews. The text updates, but with the values set at definition. onSensorChanged should update these values right?

```
import [...]

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    public float[] gravity = {0,0,0};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView gravxTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gravxTxtView);
        final TextView gravyTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gravyTxtView);
        final TextView gravzTxtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gravzTxtView);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gravxTxtView.setText("Gravity x: " + Float.toString((gravity[0])));
                gravyTxtView.setText("Gravity y: " + Float.toString((gravity[1])));
                gravzTxtview.setText("Gravity z: " + Float.toString((gravity[2])));
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            gravity[0] = event.values[0];
            gravity[1] = event.values[1];
            gravity[2] = event.values[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some serious steps you are missing 
1. Get the instance of sensor manager

```
SensorManager sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

2. Get the instance of the sensor

```
Sensor accel=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

3. Register sensor to the  lister class which implements **SensorEventListener** in your case you have implemented on the MainActivity so  it will be **this**

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

now when certain change will happen it will call the onSensorChanged method ,please let me know its working or not

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I never crossed a regisering step in the docs. It's working now (ish). I get the correct values but they don't update every x milliseconds. Don't think it has anything to do with the onSensorChanged function but rather the loop method i'm using.

Comment: check the step 3 ,the third parameter here you can change the frequency there are some default frequency available . I didn't get the last part but don't use any loop ,android sensor event follows publisher subscriber pattern ,you might want to read about this.

Comment: My bad, what i mean is the text doensn't update after the 1st time. Fixed it by simply moving the setText() in the sensor update function. Thanks a bunch! This opens up a lot.